# Unable to init ZXing on Android platform - Xamarin Forms application

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

I am wondering if someone can help with my problem of initializing ZXing barcode reader on Android platform in my Xamarin Form application.

I successfully added ZXing.Net.Mobile and ZXing.Net libraries but when I try to initialize ZXing library on Android platform with the following code:

```
global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
```

It failes to find the required classes with error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'ZXing' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

My references for Android project:

[image]

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated `ZXing.Net.Mobile` and `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms` libraries to version `2.1.0-beta1` and problem has been resolved.